# Is a runnable with non-final fields unsafe to submit to an executor?

Tags: java, concurrency

If I have code like the following:

```
  public void foo() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor().submit(
      new Runnable() {
        int x = 5;
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("x = " + x);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Am I guaranteed to see "x = 5", or could I also see "x = 0" because the `println` is being executed in a different thread that might see the uninitialized value of `x`? I've never witnessed this happen, but I've been unable to find a guarantee that this doesn't happen (for example, if `x` were `final`, then it seems it will never happen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ["happens before" relationships](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) defined in the latest JMM.  One of these points is "starting a thread" and submitting to an executor carries the same guarantees as starting a thread (see the ["memory consistency effects"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) in the javadocs).

Comment: Do you have a reference? What is special about submitting to an executor that causes synchronization, compared with any other method call?

Comment: @jonderry - added relevant links

Comment: Does the JVM guarantee this for any implementation of `Executor`, including a custom implementation that I make (as long as it implements the `Executor` interface)? If not, I guess all implementations of `Executor` should have `submit` acquire a lock and and then have the worker thread acquire the same lock?

Comment: @jonderry - no, that guarantee is only for jdk builtin implementations.  if you implement it yourself, you need to handle it yourself.  generally, using any of the java.util.concurrent constructs as part of your own implementation will work (blocking queues, Lock, concurrent collections, synchronization, etc).